# How can I setState to Active Tab from an array of Current Window Tabs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that displays a Link Preview of the current active tab but there is of course a delay of it rendering when opened as it is calling an API. I want to grab all the current window tab URLs and prerender the Link Previews to be ready, and only display the active tab when the extension is opened.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        itemURL: 'https://www.getpennywise.io'
    };
}


componentDidMount() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
        let OpenTabs = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            const itemURL = new URL(tabs[i].url);
            OpenTabs.push(itemURL);
        }
        // this.setState({
        //     itemURL: itemURL,
        console.log(OpenTabs);
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <MicrolinkCard
            url={this.state.itemURL}
            size='large'
            contrast='true'
        />
    )
}
```

I am able to get it to work for active tab = true and settings itemURL to tabs[0] but am trying to avoid the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome.* API is asynchronous so there'll be always a delay.

**Query the tabs in a script declared inside `<head>` so the results will be available sooner:**

popup.html

```html
<head>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <!-- other scripts
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
  -->     
</head>
```

popup.js

```
let tabs;

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, tabs_ => {
  tabs = tabs_;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('gotTabs'));
});

Promise.all([
  new Promise(resolve =>
    window.addEventListener('gotTabs', resolve, {once: true})),
  new Promise(resolve =>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resolve, {once: true})),
]).then(() => {
  // create component here using 'tabs' variable
});
```

**Another workaround is to always track tab activity in the background script** via various events in [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) API and save the JSON.stringify(results) in HTML5 localStorage, which is synchronous so it'll be available at the popup start.